# How to extract PDF text with custom <tab>?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I'm trying to extract the text from a PDF with a custom formatting. I am using the `PDFBox` API. I need the columns with empty field to be populated with an identifier (pipe "|", for example)

I've tried subscribing to some methods of the `PDFTextStripper` class, but to no avail. I was unable to identify at which point the white space is removed that identifies an empty field in the column.

I used this example: https://github.com/JonathanLink/PDFLayoutTextStripper. But the same only formats the spaces, what I need is that the fields that represent a cell vzia be identified with the character "|".

```
 private static void convertParaTexto(PDDocument document) throws IOException {

    PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();

    pdfStripper.setSortByPosition(true);
    pdfStripper.setWordSeparator("|");

    String text = pdfStripper.getText(document);
    document.close();
}
```

**See the original text:**

[image]

**Result of simple extraction (code above):**

[image]

**How it should be:**

[image]